# SHA 256 from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, sha, sha256, message-digest

I´m trying to create the equivalent code from Java to C# for the function below:

```
public static String SHA256 (List<String> parametros, String clave) 

{
try {
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    for(String param:parametros){
        byte p[] = new byte[param.length()];
        p = param.getBytes();
        sha.update(p);
    }
    byte bClave[] = new byte[clave.length()];
    bClave = clave.getBytes();
    byte[] hash = sha.digest(bClave);
    return ( hexString256 (hash));
   }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
   return ("Error");
  }
}
```

Any suggestions for the  `sha.update(p);` line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just about calculating SHA-256 hash of some data maybe this would give some idea:

```
// using System.Security.Cryptography;
public static string ComputeHashSha256(byte[] toBeHashed)
{
    using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sha256.ComputeHash(toBeHashed));
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If the goal is to compute hash of a list strings after concatenating them you can use an additional method like (or combine them both in a single one if you wish):

```
public static string ComputeSHA256HashOfAListOfStrings(List<string> parameters)
{
    var concatted = string.Join(string.Empty, parameters);
    var byteOfConcattedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concatted);
    return ComputeHashSha256(byteOfConcattedString);
}
```

Please note I just meant this sample to be a pointer for you because I don't exactly know what the Java code above does but I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: in this case I would like to compute the hash for string array. Should I merge all arrays of bytes and then compute the hash?

Comment: @ErnestoRodriguez I updated my answer. I hope it helps.